# Spring Boot + Spring Web Socket + RabbitMQ Web STOMP

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am working on adding live notification in my application

I have done POC with
- Spring Boot
- Spring WebSocket
- SockJS
- RabbitMQ STOMP plugin

I read about [RabbitMQ Web STOMP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html)  and want to do POC of that. But it says Since version 3.7 support for SockJS websocket emulation was removed.

Is there any example for Spring WebSocket + RabbitMQ Web STOMP with or without SockJS.

Please help.

Reference links:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Hi, I am looking for a similar working example. Could you share the code please? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@n.sharvarish... first create a websocket configuration class over rabbitmq like this...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;
    @Value("${destination.prefix}")
    private String destinationPrefix;
    @Value("${stomp.broker.relay}")
    private String stompBrokerRelay;
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay(stompBrokerRelay).setRelayHost(host).setRelayPort(port).setSystemLogin(userName).setSystemPasscode(password);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(destinationPrefix);
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(endpoint).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

---

and then ...
use above  config class  where you want to use ..
like this..

```
@Autowired
SimpMessagingTemplate template

template.convertAndSend(destinationurl, object);
```

and configure above username and password and all from application.properties